How to Use UnsafeAccessor to Check if Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope IsDisposed in .NET 8?
I'm currently working on a project using .NET 8 and Autofac for dependency injection. I've encountered a scenario where I need to check if an instance of Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope is already disposed to prevent accessing disposed objects, which leads to an ObjectDisposedException.
I came across the UnsafeAccessor as a potential solution to access private or internal members safely without reflection, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this context to check the IsDisposed property of LifetimeScope.
I try this
[UnsafeAccessor(UnsafeAccessorKind.Method, Name = "get_IsDisposed")]
private static extern ref bool GetIsDisposed(global::Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope @this);

but get exception
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.get_IsDisposed'. 

I make a simple Demo
https://dotnetfiddle.net/79xX5J
I want to get the IsDisposed property of Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope，to check if Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope is already disposed.

I need to check if an instance of Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope is already disposed why? That smells of an application bug. Why would anything other than Autofac dispose of an object? Why does application code outside the scope try to access a scoped object? Don't perform the check and use the exception to find out what's wrong in the application code. If you need to use a scoped object in a singleton, use a factory method or an explicit scope to create the scoped object when needed

Post the code that throws because it tries to access the disposed object. People can show you how to fix this. Covering up the error just means you'll get into deeper trouble

From purely technical point of view - IsDisposed is a property and is defined on Autofac.Util.Disposable (LifetimeScope inherits from it) so you need to remove the ref modifier (it is for fields) from the method declaration and use correct type:
[UnsafeAccessor(UnsafeAccessorKind.Method, Name = "get_IsDisposed")]
private static extern bool IsDisposed(Autofac.Util.Disposable c);

And usage:
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var container = builder.Build();

bool isDisposed = IsDisposed(container.BeginLifetimeScope() as Autofac.Util.Disposable);
// or
// IsDisposed(container.BeginLifetimeScope() as Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope);

Demo @dotnetfiddle.net
But in general you should avoid doing this, such approach can be brittle for multiple reasons like library authors deciding to change the internal implementation or maybe some concurrency stuff (for example scope being disposed after check but before method invocation).
Usually the correct way to handle such situations is to figure out why the scope is disposed before you want to use it and fix that (also I have a slight suspicion that you are doing some background work stuff and/or fire-and-forget but without seeing actual code this is just a guess, but if this is the case the way to handle it is to use some background processing with appropriate lifetime scopes).

The "demo" isn't really a demo - it just shows the declarations. Could you add a Main() method showing that it works without error? (Fiddle example)
I tried it but it doesn't seem to work yet.

@Matt It is a demo, press run and it will run without any errors. If you are not sure if it has run - just wrap IsDisposed(...) into a Console.WriteLine.

@Matt "I tried it but it doesn't seem to work yet" - can you please elaborate?  It works for me. What are your expectations of it working?

Take [UnsafeAccessor(UnsafeAccessorKind.Method, Name = "get_IsDisposed")] private static extern bool IsDisposed(Autofac.Util.Disposable c); and Tony's fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/79xX5J - replace the declaration there and run it. For me, it throws Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. The fiddle you provided (https://dotnetfiddle.net/XNPMVx) just contains the declarations, the main method is missing.

@Matt "it throws" - because original fiddle passes null were instance should be passed (to the IsDisposed method invocation). "the main method is missing." - no, it is not, it uses top level statements feature and the main method is generated by the compiler (it works since .NET 6 as far as I remember). As I suggested - adding Console.WrtieLine makes the "work" more noticable (updated the fiddle).

Much better! Now when you update the source code in the answer too, it is perfect. N.B. This is how unit tests work  (I mean, an assert with a boolean result and a message if it failed). But a console output is fine too! Note I just randomly saw the question and now I am able to quickly get the idea what it is about.
